# Thread Safety RijndaelManaged, ICryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, thread-safety, rijndaelmanaged

Lets say we have this code that runs in the constructor:

```
    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)
    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    Dim passPharse As String = GenerateKeyString(EncryptionKey)

    Dim password As Rfc2898DeriveBytes = New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPharse, saltValueBytes, passwordIterations)

    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(CInt(keySize / 8))

    mSymmetricKey = New RijndaelManaged()
    mSymmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

    mSymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    mSymmetricKey.BlockSize = 128

    mSymmetricKey.Key = keyBytes
    mSymmetricKey.IV = initVectorBytes

    mDecryptor = mSymmetricKey.CreateDecryptor()
    mEncryptor = mSymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor()
```

and then 2 public functions:

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String) As String
    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = mEncryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

    Dim cipherText As String = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)

    Return cipherText
End Function
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String) As String
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)

    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = mDecryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBytes, 0, cipherTextBytes.Length)

    Dim plainText As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

    Return plainText
End Function
```

Would it be threadsafe to call those from more than one thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation it is not thread safe. You will have [RijndaelManagedTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanagedtransform.aspx) instances in the `mDecryptor` and `mEncryptor` variables. [TransformFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanagedtransform.transformfinalblock.aspx) is an instance method which according to MSDN is not thread safe:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual
>   Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

If you want to be guaranteed to have a thread safe code you might need to synchronize the call to TransformFinalBlock method.

Comment: thanks i hoped that i had missed some thing, i guess ill just use [ThreadStatic] to solve the problem...